# Infragistics WebImageButton does not trigger click event on postback when clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, infragistics, confirmation

I'm designing a page that has an `Infragistics` `WebImageButton`.
When clicking on that button I display a confirmation box.
If user clicks "OK", postback occurs that needs to trigger my click event, but it does not.

Here is what I have:

My `webimagebutton`:

```
<td><igtxt:webimagebutton id="btnHandle" runat="server" text="Process" usebrowserdefaults="False" cssclass="bodytext">
    <clientsideevents click="confirmProcess"></clientsideevents>
    <RoundedCorners MaxHeight="80" ImageUrl="ig_butXP1wh.gif" MaxWidth="400" HoverImageUrl="ig_butXP2wh.gif"
     RenderingType="FileImages" PressedImageUrl="ig_butXP4wh.gif" DisabledImageUrl="ig_butXP5wh.gif"
     FocusImageUrl="ig_butXP3wh.gif"></RoundedCorners>
    </igtxt:webimagebutton>
</td>
```

My client-side function:

```
function confirmBoarding(oButton,oEvent)
{
    var strMessage = "Are you sure you want to proceed?\nIf yes, press OK, otherwise CANCEL";
    if(!confirm(strMessage))
    {
        oEvent.cancel = true;
        return false;}
    }                    
    return;
}
```

My click event in code-behind:

```
private void btnHandle_Click(object sender, Infragistics.WebUI.WebDataInput.ButtonEventArgs e)
{
   String here = "I'm here";//never gets hit
}
```

My code-behind method never gets hit.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank's

Comment: Where is the event handler wired up?  I don't see it in the markup, are you doing this somewhere in the code behind?  If not, maybe you just need to wire up the event handler.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I already found the problem, but thank you for the answer!!!

Comment: I added this as an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have wired up the event.  From the markup provided and the C# code there is no evidence that the event is wired up.